# Where to locate open4gl jar dependency?

Tags: java, maven, opengl

Good Morning Commmunity.

I have inherited a project that require a open4gl jar file inorder to build
as specified by the projects pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.progress</groupId>
<artifactId>open4gl</artifactId>
<version>10.1B02</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, this dependency does not exist in the maven repsoitory and I have search
high and low for it. It does not appear available anywhere on the internet.

Does anyone know what this dependency is and where I could get it. I am
literally lost.

Thank-you Kindly

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your groupID and you artifactId are correct ?

i find in internet some thing like this :

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.progress.open4gl</groupId>
        <artifactId>o4glrt</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.B</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>\java\o4glrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

if you have the file you can make it in your .m2/repository/com/progress/open4gl/10.1B02 and you try.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question when looking for openedge dependency myself but couldn't find anything on internet. The following is what I used and my project is working now. Select the openedge version you need. I used 11.6.1.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>o4glrt</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>sslj</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecore</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecore.xmi</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecore.sdo</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecore.change</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>cryptoj</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>certj</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openedge</groupId>
        <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
        <version>${openedge.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```